# error Cannot implicitly convert type when Join Merged Data Table using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have to display chat from xml file. But when I join 2 merged tables, there are some errors.

The error is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) D:\ChatReport\ChatReport\Default.aspx.cs 109 42 ChatReport

```
    public void  chatload2()
    {
        DataTable dtmsg = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtmsgtxt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtmsgbody = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtuserinfo = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtnewparty = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtbodyuser = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtmerge = new DataTable();


        XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("chattest.xml"));
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);

        dtmsg = ds.Tables["message"];
        dtmsgtxt = ds.Tables["msgText"];
        dtuserinfo = ds.Tables["userInfo"];
        dtnewparty = ds.Tables["newParty"];

        dtbodyuser = dtnewparty.Copy();
        dtbodyuser.Merge(dtuserinfo);
        dtbodyuser.Columns.Remove("timeShift");
        dtbodyuser.Columns.Remove("eventid");
        dtbodyuser.Columns.Remove("chatTranscript_Id");
        dtbodyuser.Columns.Remove("personId");
        //dtbodyuser.Columns.Remove("newParty_Id");
        dtbodyuser.Columns.Remove("visibility");
        dtbodyuser.AcceptChanges();
        DataTable dt = dtbodyuser;

        dtmsgbody = dtmsg.Copy();
        dtmsgbody.Merge(dtmsgtxt);
        dtmsgbody.AcceptChanges();

        DataTable dt10 = new DataTable();

        IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from dtquer in dtmsgbody.AsEnumerable()
                                     join dtusr in dtbodyuser.AsEnumerable()
                                     on dtquer.Field<string>("userId") equals
                                     dtusr.Field<string>("userId")

                                     select new  
                    {

                        userId = dtquer.Field<string>("userId"),
                        userNick = dtusr.Field<string>("userNick"),
                        timeShift = dtquer.Field<int>("timeShift"),
                        message_Id = dtquer.Field<int>("message_Id"),
                        msgText_Text = dtquer.Field<string>("msgText_Text")


                    };


        dt10 = query.CopyToDataTable();


        //dtmerge = dtmsgbody.Copy();
        //dtmerge.Merge(dtbodyuser);
        //dtmerge.AcceptChanges();
        dtmerge = dtmsgbody.Copy();
        dtmsgbody.Merge(dt);
        dtmerge.AcceptChanges();
        //dtbodyuser = dtmsgbody.Copy();
        //dtbodyuser.Merge(dtuserinfo);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt10.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            string output = dtmerge.Rows[i]["msgText_Text"].ToString() + "\n";
            txtchatmerge.Text += output + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

Comment: Notice that you expect a query result of type IEnumerable<DataRow>, yet the query returns a list of objects of an anonymous type (that you build inside "select new").
Either change "IEnumerable<dataRow> query" to "var query" and work with the anonymous type result set, or change the query to return a collection of DataRow instances.

Comment: if i change to "var query" there is no error but matter is the function"dt10 = query.CopyToDataTable();" is not working. how to work with anonymos query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling specifically for IEnumerable of type DataRow and then selecting an IEnumerable type Anonymous into it--you'll need to specify that the anonymous types are actually DataRow objects:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from dtquer in dtmsgbody.AsEnumerable()
                                 join dtusr in dtbodyuser.AsEnumerable()
                                 on dtquer.Field<string>("userId") equals
                                 dtusr.Field<string>("userId")

                                 select new DataRow
                                 [

                                     dtquer.Field<string>("userId"),
                                     dtusr.Field<string>("userNick"),
                                     dtquer.Field<int>("timeShift"),
                                     dtquer.Field<int>("message_Id"),
                                     dtquer.Field<string>("msgText_Text")

                                 ];
```

Alternately, make the "query" object less specific using "var", so the type you're selecting can dictate what the IEnumerable is made of:

```
var query = from dtquer in dtmsgbody.AsEnumerable()
                                 join dtusr in dtbodyuser.AsEnumerable()
                                 on dtquer.Field<string>("userId") equals
                                 dtusr.Field<string>("userId")

                                 select new  
                {

                    userId = dtquer.Field<string>("userId"),
                    userNick = dtusr.Field<string>("userNick"),
                    timeShift = dtquer.Field<int>("timeShift"),
                    message_Id = dtquer.Field<int>("message_Id"),
                    msgText_Text = dtquer.Field<string>("msgText_Text")


                };
```

Tho you'll need DataRows later in your code for CopyToDataTable(), so for my money, I'd take the first approach myself rather than use "var" with anonymous types that I'd need to convert down the road.

**EDIT**

In response to what was called out in the comments, moving away from the reliance on Copy() might be the better solution. By defining the table structure, then assigning the desired values to the appropriate columns, you get around around the conversion issues.

```
DataTable dt10 = new DataTable();

dt10.Columns.Add("UserId");
dt10.Columns.Add("Nickname");
dt10.Columns.Add("TimeShift");
dt10.Columns.Add("MessageId");
dt10.Columns.Add("MessageText");

var query = from dtquer in dtmsgbody.AsEnumerable()
            join dtusr in dtbodyuser.AsEnumerable()
            on dtquer.Field<string>("userId") equals
            dtusr.Field<string>("userId")

            select new
            {

                userId = dtquer.Field<string>("userId"),
                userNick = dtusr.Field<string>("userNick"),
                timeShift = dtquer.Field<int>("timeShift"),
                message_Id = dtquer.Field<int>("message_Id"),
                msgText_Text = dtquer.Field<string>("msgText_Text")


             };

var counter = 0;

foreach (var row in query)
{
     dt10.NewRow();
     var newRow = dt10.Rows[counter];

     newRow.ItemArray[0] = row.userId;
     newRow.ItemArray[1] = row.userNick;
     newRow.ItemArray[2] = row.timeShift;
     newRow.ItemArray[3] = row.message_Id;
     newRow.ItemArray[4] = row.msgText_Text;

     counter++;
 }

 // Should end up with dt10 having all the results from the query above loaded into it
```

Difficult to check without having your dependencies, but that initial error you reported is no longer showing in my Visual Studio.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What isn't working, in what way?

Comment: these are my merged tables.dtmsg = ds.Tables["message"];
   dtmsgtxt = ds.Tables["msgText"];
   dtuserinfo = ds.Tables["userInfo"];
   dtnewparty = ds.Tables["newParty"];

   dtbodyuser = dtnewparty.Copy();
   dtbodyuser.Merge(dtuserinfo);
            
   dtbodyuser.AcceptChanges();
   DataTable dt = dtbodyuser;

  dtmsgbody = dtmsg.Copy();
            dtmsgbody.Merge(dtmsgtxt);
            dtmsgbody.AcceptChanges();    i need to merge all filed in a single table. when i try your query not worked. im not fimiliar with linq query. please help

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) D:\ChatReport\ChatReport\Default.aspx.cs 109 42 ChatReport        can you review my earlier code and i need end solution to get a single table that contains "userid,nickname,timeshift,messagetext"

Comment: I see it's a compiler error, not an exception--my fault. I also updated my answer to something that is a bit clunky but should get you around this block.

Comment: sorry for late reply  

                                 select new  
                {

                    userId = dtquer.Field<string>("userId"),
                    userNick = dtusr.Field<string>("userNick"),
                    timeShift = dtquer.Field<int>("timeShift"),
                    message_Id = dtquer.Field<int>("message_Id"),
                    msgText_Text = dtquer.Field<string>("msgText_Text")


                };  this code worked for me and i Converted to string and timedate evry field inslide selectcommand. thank you very much

Comment: Wonderful, I'm glad I could help!